# Cruise Control.Net Server error: Error 1053: Ther service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, windows-server-2003

I'm unable to re-start my CruiseControl.NET Server Service lately.

The console version runs alright though.

I get the error below when I run the service:

Could not start the CruiseControl.NET Server service on Local Computer

Error 1053: Ther service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

The text below dispalys ther application error in my event view:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   Application Error
Event Category: (100)
Event ID:   1000
Date:       13/10/11
Time:       03:29:59
User:       N/A
Computer:   AUTHEWS01-V
Description:
Faulting application ccservice.exe, version 1.6.7981.1, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 5.2.3790.4480, fault address 0x0000bef7.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
Data:
0000: 41 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74   Applicat
0008: 69 6f 6e 20 46 61 69 6c   ion Fail
0010: 75 72 65 20 20 63 63 73   ure  ccs
0018: 65 72 76 69 63 65 2e 65   ervice.e
0020: 78 65 20 31 2e 36 2e 37   xe 1.6.7
0028: 39 38 31 2e 31 20 69 6e   981.1 in
0030: 20 6b 65 72 6e 65 6c 33    kernel3
0038: 32 2e 64 6c 6c 20 35 2e   2.dll 5.
0040: 32 2e 33 37 39 30 2e 34   2.3790.4
0048: 34 38 30 20 61 74 20 6f   480 at o
0050: 66 66 73 65 74 20 30 30   ffset 00
0058: 30 30 62 65 66 37         00bef7
```

I'd appreciate some help, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I most commonly see the CCNET service fail like that either because the user credentials which the service is running under are invalid, or because the configuration has been broken badly enough that CCNET can't process it at startup.

So check the service user identity first - is the user still a valid one? Is the password right?

Then run your config through CCValidator just in case there's something in there that the commandline version is ignoring but is tripping the service up. Also compare the application config files - something could be broken in the service config but not the commandline config.

Comment: Cheers mate. My ccnet.config file passess validation with CCValidator. Are there any other xml files to validate, besides ccnet.config? I would have to verify if either password/identity has changed from IT.

Comment: Yep, check ccservice.exe.config - that's the application configuration file which is read by the service before it processes your project definitions in ccnet.config.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was because .net framework 2.0/3.5 was not installed on a server :)
Fixed by installing that framework.